# match only exact word/string in python

Tags: python

How to match exact string/word while searching a list. I have tried, but its not correct. below I have given the sample list, my code and the test results

```
list = ['Hi, friend', 'can you help me?']
```

my code

```
dic=dict()
for item in list:
    for word in item.split():
        dic.setdefault(word, list()).append(item)

print dic.get(s)
```

test results:

```
s = "can" ~ expected output: 'can you help me?' ~ output I get: 'can you help me?'
s = "you" ~ expected output: *nothing* ~ output I get: 'can you help me?'
s = "Hi," ~ expected output: 'Hi, friend' ~ output I get: 'Hi, friend'
s = "friend" ~ expected output: *nothing* ~ output I get: 'Hi, friend'
```

My list contains 1500 strings. Anybody can help me??

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by exact matching. Do you mean it has to start with a specific word? The word has to be somewhere in the string?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What you are asking is `How to match exact string/word while searching a list.` but from your example what I understand is you are just searching for the prefix match i.e. if the word that you are searching is the first word in the phrase.

Comment: Hi Abhijit, I want prefix match. Example: string "can you help me??"

Comment: If we search "Can" we need to get "can you help me??" otherwise doesnot need to match anything. Can you got it Abhijit??

Comment: Just see my example or Anurag's. Which ever suit's you, you can go with it..

Comment: Ohhh so the match should be case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a map of sentences and their starting word, so you don't need to map all words in that sentence but only the first one.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sentences = ['Hi, friend', 'can you help me?']

start_sentence_map = defaultdict(list)
for sentence in sentences:
    start = sentence.split()[0]
    start_sentence_map[start].append(sentence)

for s in ["can", "you", "Hi,", "friend"]:
    print s,":",start_sentence_map.get(s)
```

output:

```
can : ['can you help me?']
you : None
Hi, : ['Hi, friend']
friend : None
```

Also note few things from the code above

1. Don't use name `list` as name of variable because python uses it for `list class`
2. Use default dict which makes it easy to directly add entries to dictionary instead of first adding a default entry
3. Better descriptive names instead of mylist, or dic

Answer (score 1):

In case if you just want to see if the sentence starts with a given words you can try `startswith` if you don;t want the searched word to be at word boundary or `split()[0]` if you want it to match at word boundary. As an example

```
>>> def foo(s): # @ word boundary
    return [x for x in l if x.split()[0]==s]

>>> def bar(s): # Prefix
    return [x for x in l if x.startswith(s)]
```

Also refrain from overlaying python global name-space like what you did when you named your list as `list`. I have called it `l` in my example.